# How to select min & max values of subset groups

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get my head round the following problem, I have a tracking device that updates its location and online state every minute. I'm trying to split this data up into separate journeys by grouping an online state into several small subsets of a select statement.

I know I can select the min & max and union these for the table as a whole but I'm unsure how to do this for each group where its online state is true.

Whilst I can achieve the desired result in code I need to move this operation to the server for over the wire performance reasons.

Could anyone help point me in the right direction to break this down into a sql statement?

```
[positions]
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int          unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| device_id         | int          unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lat               | double                | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| lng               | double                | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| date_time         | datetime              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| online            | bit                   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Example data

```
id  device_id   lat     lng     date_time             online
14  1           0.1     0.1     2014-07-11 05:21:37   0
17  1           0.11    0.11    2014-07-11 05:22:37   1 
18  1           0.12    0.12    2014-07-11 05:23:37   1
24  1           0.13    0.13    2014-07-11 05:24:37   1
25  1           0.14    0.14    2014-07-11 05:25:37   1
26  1           0.14    0.14    2014-07-11 05:26:37   0
45  1           0.14    0.14    2014-07-11 05:27:37   0
47  1           0.14    0.14    2014-07-11 05:28:37   1
56  1           0.13    0.13    2014-07-11 05:29:37   1
67  1           0.12    0.12    2014-07-11 05:30:37   1
68  1           0.11    0.11    2014-07-11 05:31:37   1
78  1           0.11    0.11    2014-07-11 05:32:37   0
```

Desired result

```
StartDateTime        StartLat StartLng  FinishDateTime       FinishLat FinishLng
2014-07-11 05:22:37  0.11     0.11      2014-07-11 05:25:37  0.14      0.14
2014-07-11 05:28:37  0.14     0.14      2014-07-11 05:31:37  0.11      0.11
```

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Comment: Is it fair to assume that in the general case, there could be more than one device ID active at a time, which is why there are gaps in the ID numbers for Device ID = 1?

Comment: Yes that's correct Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to characterize each group.  The easiest way is to count the number of `online = 0` before each row:

```
select device_id, min(date_time) as StartDateTime, max(date_time) as FinishDateTime,
       substring_index(group_concat(lat order by datetime asc), ',', 1) as StartLat,
       substring_index(group_concat(long order by datetime asc), ',', 1) as StartLong,
       substring_index(group_concat(lat order by datetime desc), ',', 1) as EndLat,
       substring_index(group_concat(long order by datetime desc), ',', 1) as EndLong
from (select e.*,
             (select count(*)
              from example e2
              where e2.device_id = e.device_id and
                    e2.date_time <= e.date_time and
                    e2.online = 0
             ) as grp
      from example e
      where e.online = 1
     ) e
group by device_id, grp;
```

This uses the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick to get the first and last values.

```
select t.*,
       efirst.lat as firstLat, efirst.long as firstLong,
       ellast.lat as lastLat, elast.long as lastLong
from (select device_id, min(date_time) as StartDateTime, max(date_time) as FinishDateTime
      from (select e.*,
                   (select count(*)
                    from example e2
                    where e2.device_id = e.device_id and
                          e2.date_time <= e.date_time and
                          e2.online = 0
                   ) as grp
            from example e
            where e.online = 1
           ) e
      group by device_id, grp
     ) t join
     example efirst
     on efirst.device_id = t.device_id and efirst.date_time = FirstDateTime join
     example elast
     on elast.device_id = t.device_id and elast.date_time = FinishDateTime;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, will take a look at substring & group concat to better understand your answer

Comment: @StephenManderson . . . You can also get the first and last coordinates by joining back to the original table on `device_id` and `datetime`; I just find the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick easy enough when you are already doing an aggregation.

Comment: Do you recon there is much difference in performance with the two methods you suggest? That is with the above solution, I'll need to cast the blob values back to their original type. Or would using a join cost more?

Comment: The reason I ask is that the start,end - lat,lng are returned as blobs, and from what I can find out about mysql I can't convert these back to double.

Comment: Oh, in that case doing the join back to the original table is probably better.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Gordon, it's appreciated.